# How can I set the Csv file's cellwidth while exporting data to an excel sheet using Angular2Csv library?

Tags: excel, angular, csv

I am working with angular and i am trying to export json data to a Csv file.

Here is the code snippet:

```
exportToExcel(event)
{
    console.log("Exporting to excel in progress...");
    if (this.usersDevice)
    {
        let items = this.parseHtmlToJson();
        let component = new Angular2Csv(items, 'UsersDevicesList', this.exportToExcelOptions);
    }
}
```

I am passing the Json object(items), the filename and the Options as parameters to the Angular2Csv's Constructor.

Is there any way I could set the cell width of the CSV file?
Could I pass the cellwidth with the "this.exportToExcelOptions" object or is there any other way?

Here's how this.exportToExcelOptions looks like,

```
private exportToExcelOptions:any = { 
    fieldSeparator: ',',
    quoteStrings: '"',
    decimalseparator: '.',
    showLabels: true, 
    showTitle: false,
    useBom: true
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is no 'cell width' in csv format

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What is the way to set the width of the column in the csv file to make it look better?

Comment: csv is simple text format - there is no cells there, no rows, just some data divided with commas.